# How to populate message properties to RabbitMQ using WSO2 ESB as RabbitMQ Message Producer

Tags: wso2-esb

I've already configured WSO2 ESB as RabbitMQ Messaage Producer according to [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/ESB+as+a+RabbitMQ+Message+Producer) and using REST Proxy service I am able to publish message to RabbitMQ using REST post method (content-type: application/json) but how can I populate properties to amqp message properties using json because all headers are copied to amqp message headers and body of post method (json) is treated as data of amqp message. Is it possible? Why how it exactly works is not documented?

Comment: Are you referring on publishing custom message properties?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that headers from REST Post method are copied to AMQP message headers, body of the REST Post method are copied to AMQP message payload and properties of the AMQP message are added by the WSO2 ESB but I don't know how can I pass for example messageId from the REST Post method to the AMPQ message properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I resolved it writing the .class org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer.getBasicProperties. The code is at https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/message/store/impl/rabbitmq/RabbitMQProducer.java

and I add:

```
private BasicProperties getBasicProperties(MessageContext synCtx, StorableMessage storableMessage)
{
    String sKey = "";
    Map<String, Object> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        Iterator iKeys =  synCtx.getPropertyKeySet().iterator();
        while(iKeys.hasNext() ){
            sKey = iKeys.next().toString();
            if (sKey.toUpperCase().startsWith("RABBIT_HEAD")) {
                headerMap.put(sKey.replace("RABBIT_HEAD_", ""), synCtx.getProperty(sKey).toString());
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.toString());
    }
    BasicProperties.Builder builder = new BasicProperties().builder();
    if (!headerMap.isEmpty()) {
        builder.headers(headerMap);
    }
    builder.messageId(synCtx.getMessageID());
    builder.deliveryMode(MessageProperties.MINIMAL_PERSISTENT_BASIC.getDeliveryMode());
    builder.priority(Integer.valueOf(storableMessage.getPriority(0)));
    return builder.build();
}
```

In a proxy or api, I declared properties as:

```
<property name="RABBIT_HEAD_x-delay" expression="get-property('seconds')" />
```